# browse-url-generic-program as a safe-local-variable-values

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, emacs

I've been using a lot the `.dir-locals.el` file for all of my different projects (personal / work / community / etc) and I have defined a couple of settings depending on the project.

Today, I tried to change the value of `browse-url-generic-program` since I need Google Chrome for my work and Firefox for my personal projects. So, I added this to my `.dir-locals.el`

```
((nil
  . (
     ;; use Firefox as browser for this project
     (browse-url-generic-program . "firefox")
     )))
```

and also I have this in my `.emacs` because the documentation says that it's a **risky variable**:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(safe-local-variable-values
   (quote
    ((browse-url-generic-program "firefox")
     (browse-url-generic-program "google-chrome")))))
```

and I can see this message in the description/documentation of this variable:

```
browse-url-generic-program’s value is "google-chrome"
Original value was nil

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
  However, you have added it to ‘safe-local-variable-values’.
```

But Emacs still keep asking me about `The local variables list in /home/humitos/ contains variables that are risky (**). Do you want to apply it?` and the only variable mentioned there is `browse-url-generic-program` with the value `"firefox"`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For some reason, this particular variable `browse-url-generic-program` has to be defined like `     (browse-url-generic-program . "firefox")` in the `safe-local-variable-values` (note that I'm adding a dot between the symbol and the value, as the documentation of this variable mentions). Anyway, I don't understand why all the other variables that I have defined as safe, don't need this dot (`.`)

Comment: The docs for `safe-local-variable-values` says each element is a cons like `(var . val)`.  If you use the customize UI, it will automatically ensure a cons is added instead of a two element list.  You should not edit `custom-set-variables` by hand, because it's often hard to get the syntax correct. 
  Either use `setq` and similar in your init.el, or use customize.

Comment: The thing is that I'm setting `custom-set-variables` by hand when emacs starts and I have other variables like this:

    `(elpy-test-django-runner-command "docker" "exec" "-it" "ondemand_shell_run_1" "python" "manage.py" "test" "--keepdb")`

(note it doesn't have the `.` in the middle)

and they work properly. So, I don't understand why it work for these cases but not for `browse-url-generic-program`

Comment: **You should not edit custom-set-variables by hand, because it's often hard to get the syntax correct.**  I'm guessing it's because a cons with a list as the cdr looks the same as a bigger list with the car as the first element.  `(equal '(foo . (bar baz)) '(foo bar baz))`.  This is because a list is a bunch of nested conses like `(foo . (bar . (baz . nil)))`.